# What rotation rules can be applied to stacked cubes to make a 3D spirograph?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, rotations

If you arrange building blocks for example toy cubes so that every next cube is tilted over its base by 30 degrees and rotated to it's right by 12 degrees, it would wind through space in a helical fashion.

What rules can be applied to pivot the blocks so that they create assymetrical spirograph structures?

Examples of rules for n building blocks can be if(n=17) then rot(y)= n/17*10... any kind of rotation of the blocks relative to n. The structure is built by rotating blocks so it isn't a parametric structure which can place the blocks and then line them up.

ADDENDUM- Another view of the problem... All polygons from 3 to 100 sides, must have angles that add up to 360. if i can rotate some lines of the polygon outwards in 3D, to make polygons with n sides, like 800 sides, I want to know how to add together the angles so that they form a closed mobeous polygon similar to spirographs and so on. the cubes can be viewed as lines also. Perhaps i have to simplify all the subsequent angles into 3 point triangles.

[image]

Comment: if i tilt them by 20 and rotate them by i/20 when i%20=0 ... (20,40,60....), then the object returns to it's start and has 2 planes of symmetry unlile a spirograph which should not have any symmetry in 3d.

Comment: My program has a complex error using non quaternion rotation, where it flips objects by 180 degrees over a certain rotation, which makes a spirograph with a simple symmetry, i am thinking perhaps if i flip the blocks so that they repeat a pattern ever 30 degres or so may make a complex spirograph, but i haven't found the solution still. I can't even make a star shape with this construcion method, radiating from the center. I should try to solve that to start with.

Comment: Only with more detail it may be possible to help. What is the pattern to generate? Right now guessing. Is it like gyro gimbal lock? Euler angles? (3D spirograph printer is template with holes made by 3Dprinting material rather than plastic material, not connected with this)

Comment: here is a 3d spirograph: ......       https://maxwelldemon.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/spiros2.png        .....     http://maxwelldemon.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/spiros.png?w=450&h=337

Answer (score 4):

For a helix you did already, the positions of each block is given by:

$$ (x,y,z) = ( a \cos \theta, a \sin \theta,  c \cdot  \theta, )  $$

where $c$ is the pitch through which the spiral advances for 1 turn. Choose your $c$ depending on how fast you want to climb, $a$ on how big your helix base should be, and also choose a small enough $\theta $ increment.

If $ \alpha $ is helix angle,

$$ \dfrac{\Delta z }{a\, \Delta \theta } =\tan \alpha = \dfrac ca$$

So all you have to do is rotate one block around axis of $x$ or $y$ by an amount $ \alpha$ to keep it slanted, keep it eccentric by distance $a$ from central axis and make multiple copies adding $ \Delta \theta$ and $ \Delta z $ *together /at the same time / simultaneously* for rotation and climbing respectively.

For non-helical structure you should know *$ a \; priori$* by a design formula how it spreads in 3-D space or  by how much each pivot / joint should be rotated.

Nice picture. What software was used for visualizing it?

EDIT 1:

A minimal surface tubular model is shown where all its tubes cut at $90^0.$ I can give $(r, \theta, z)$ formula if you find it of any interest.You may need to rotate your blocks $(\theta)$ and push them up $(z)$ in the same way.

[image: MinimalCAT]

[image: Artful spiral]

Comment: Hi thanks, i am confused what figures to put on the x and y rotation of every block, for example as a function of i = block iterations, what x-tilt and y-rotation would be? The program is Unity3D, it does point clouds, stream processing, c#, audio and codes can be compiled and played in real-time, it's supposed to be a game engine, it's convenient for all kinds of multimedia experiments, even using gravity and so on. pro version for compiling to PC costs alot though, free only compiles web apps.

Comment: For non-helical structure you should know apriori by a design formula how it spreads in 3-D space or by how much each pivot / joint should be rotated.... this is a vague answer... very vague!!!

Comment: What I stated was for a single filament. with helix angle = $ \alpha,  $ It should be copied as many times as you need. Reflecting about one x/y axis gives $ -\alpha$ stack.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the explanation. I would like a solution in terms of rotations per cube, rotation rules.... above example seems to be roughly: 1/ twist and pivot every segment by 10 degrees, 2/every 20 iterations, twist by 180' (to make S shape) 3/every iteration (i + 10)%20 , pivot by 90 degrees. The original question was for assymetrical spirograph structures?

Comment: The cube sequence isn't really based on any x/y axes, it has no graph rules, it has angular progression rules based on the block number, so the blocks have individual axes and rotations only, they rules are similar to a growing protein made of molecules, every building block has a specific angle and rotation, and every n blocks can have a different one, or the rotations can gradually change as a function of the sequence number. Thanks very much for your help. I am just struggling to rewrite your illustration as a function of twist/pivot of blocks over n blocks.

Comment: --- update... i have managed to make similar axial symmetry spirographs similar to the one in the pic using the hint you provided... cube sequence rules are... going forwards 20 iterations, twist rotate any pattern, go backwards from 20 to 0 again rotation inversed, and every i=40 rotate +90, ever i = 80 rotate -90.

Comment: When you talked about quaternions, you should be in a situation to find parametric equations of lines in a spherical coordinate system.Your given illustration is a creation of mathematical art, about which you are inquiring here in Math SE forum.We can go further only on particular queries. I also played a bit like in the above. Anyways, good luck!

Comment: All polygons from 3 to 100 sides, must have angles that add up to 360. if i can rotate the line of the polygon outwards in 3D, to make polygons with n sides, like 800 sides, I want to know how to add together the angles so that they form a closed mobeous polygon similar to spirographs and so on. Thanks Alot! Making a complex Moebeous / Spirograph using assemblies of cubes is similar to making a fractals for example a Koch Snowflake using lines. it is a difficult puzzle which i haven't solved entirely!